# OpenGL co-ordinate mapping to device co-ordinate

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have gone through so many tutorial & also implemented some small apps in OpenGL.Stil I have confusion over the mapping of OpenGL co-ordinate system to android view co-ordinate system.
      I faced the problem while I was trying to display a texture as full screen.Somehow by hit&trial method I was able to show the texture as full screen,but has so many doubts for which I could not proceed fast.

1. In OpenGL co-ordinate system starts with left-bottom(as origin),whereas in device left-    top as origin.How things are mapped correctly to device.
2. In OpenGL we specify vertices range start from -1 to 1.How these range maps to device where it ranges from 0 to width & height.
3. Can vertices be mapped exactly the same way as the device co-ordinate.Like vertex with 0,100  maps to device co-ordinates with 0,100.

While trying to show texture as fullscreen,I changed the code according to some blogs&it worked.Here is the changes.

```
glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1);  from  glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1);  

 &   vertices[] = {                            
       0, 0,
      width, 0,
      width, height,                
      0, height
      };

  from  {-1,-1,
          1,-1,
         -1,1,
           1,1}
```

Plz help me to understand the co-ordinate mapping.

Answer (score 1):

what you set the glOrtho to the width and the height opengl is going to stretch that to fit the device you are using, say your width = 320 and height = 480 when you make glOrth(0,width,height,0,1,-1) opengl stretches that to fit your screen so the coordinates can be whatever you want them to be by setting the width and height of glOrth()

Comment: Indeed, this is how it works. Also as you noticed by default OpenGL's Y axis is increasing in an upwards direction. To map things to the way it behaves on the device you can do glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1). To get coordinates in the middle of pixels you can then do a glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0f);